# Is any limit for transaction by sftp and how to configure it?

Tags: php, wrapper, sftp, libssh2

I`ve used a wrappers for sftp connection [ssh2.sftp](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.ssh2.php). Transmission speed is become very slow after few transactions, when we used one session handle for all transactions. But transmission speed is OK after re-connection. 
Example:

```
  /**
  * Returns handle for sftp subsystem
  * @param string
  * @return handle 
  */
  function methodForConnect(...){
    //some connection code.
  }   

  ///First way. 1 connection for all transactions, becomes slow after 76 iteration.

  $sftp  = methodForConnect();
  for($i = 0; $i < 2500; $i++){
    $data = str_reapeat(rand(0, 1), 1024*1024);
    file_put_contents("ssh2.sftp://$sftp/path/to/file", $data);
  }  


  ///Second way. New connection per transaction.

  for($i = 0; $i < 2500; $i++){
    $sftp  = methodForConnect();
    $data = str_reapeat(rand(0, 1), 1024*1024);
    file_put_contents("ssh2.sftp://$sftp/path/to/file", $data);
  }
```

Is there any way to solve problem without re-connection? Thanks.

Comment: Does anybody know something about it?